# can't get sIFR to work

Tags: sifr

I have tried using sIFR on a test page http://www.irwinassociates.eu/test.php without success. I have checked and re-checked but can't find what's wrong. I figure it's something simple. Can anyone help please? Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source of the page you linked to and didn't see any javascript code in place that calls the sIFR activate() or replace() functions.  Follow the methods used on the official sIFR 3 demo page (view source) http://dev.novemberborn.net/sifr3/beta2/demo/

```
var font = { src: 'gillsans.swf' };

sIFR.activate(font);

sIFR.replace(font, {
selector: 'h1'
, css: ['.sIFR-root { color: #CCCCCC; }' ]
});
```

Comment: Okay - thanks, I'll check. I'm sure I did have and tried the debug script instead. Silly of me not to change it back...

Comment: Okay, so I have changed it back again. It was a COMMA I was missing!

Thanks